# Hibernate search - The SearchFactory was not initialized

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I'm trying to use hibernate search.
Following this guide http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/ I've added this two lines to hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</property>
<property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">/var/lucene/indexes</property>
```

And in the method where will start hibernate session I've put code to sync the search index (as written into the guide).

```
    // Hibernate starting
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry =
            new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(
                            configuration.getProperties()
                    ).build();
    // ~Hibernate starting

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);

    // Close Hibernate session
    try{
        fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
        log.info("Hibernate search index created.");
    }catch(InterruptedException e ){
        log.error( "Error during the Sync of Hibernate search on startup.", e );
    }
    try{

        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }catch( Exception ex ){

        try{
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }catch( Exception ex2 ){}
        log.error( ex  );

    }finally{
        if( session.isOpen() ){
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I start the web-app I receive this error:

```
ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000222: The SearchFactory was not initialized
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5954)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I am having the same issue, on WildFly 9.0.1.Final

Comment: @VijayKumar I have not tried yet, but i think the problem occurs because i'm using the xml file and not the annotation to describe the DB structure to hibernate. If you try let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

for me this code snipset is working. I am creating the factory in a different way. From your Stacktrace I could not see which line causes the error:

```
      SessionFactory factory = new   
      Configuration().configure("/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml").
      buildSessionFactory();
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
      session.getTransaction().begin();
      try {
        fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
        System.out.println("Hibernate search index created.");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    try {
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        try {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        } catch (Exception ex2) {
        }
        ex.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        if (session.isOpen()) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```